# Convert numbers to another one in the same range, and back

Tags: php, math, theory

I'm looking for a solution to convert all numbers in a given range to another number in the same range, and later convert that number back.

More concrete, let's say I have the numbers `1..100`.

The easiest way to convert all numbers to another one in the same range is to use: `b = 99 -a;` later get the original with `a = 99 - b;`.

My problem is that **I want to simulate some randomness**.

I want to implement this in PHP, but the coding language doesn't matter.

**WHY?**

You maybe say why? Good question :)

I am generating some easy to read short code string based on `id`-s, and because the id's are incremented one by one, my consecutive short codes are too similar. 
Later I need to "decode" the short codes, to get the id.

What my algorithm is doing now is:

`0000001 -> ababac`, `0000002 -> ababad`, `0000003 -> ababaf`, etc.

later

`ababac -> 0000001`, `ababad -> 0000002`, `ababaf -> 0000003`, etc.

So before I actually generate the short code I want to "randomize" the number as much as possible.

Comment: why dont you just have a database of conversion? i.e each record has a "real" id, and a "random md5" string or something.

Comment: What's easier than the plain 00001?

Comment: Yes this is a possible solution, I can generate unique, random, easy to read short codes and save them in db. But I would love to solve this problem without that. Just for the challenge. If I don't find a solution this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution based on module operator, on the math forum.
The solution can be found here:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/259891/function-to-convert-each-number-in-a-m-n-to-another-number-in-the-same-range

Answer (score 1):

Option 1:
Why dont you just have a database of conversion? i.e each record has a "real" id, and a "random md5" string or something

Option 2:
Use a rainbow table - maybe even a MD5 lookup table for the range 0 - 10,000 or whatever. Then just do a hashtable lookup

Comment: +1 for the rainbow table idea. In meantime I found a solution on a math forum. See my answer. Thank's for your help.